# Iterating over a session variable in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am wondering how can an iterate over a session , to which I am assigning a list of string in an action method.
I want to display each of the elements in the session as links via the for loop.
Any help is appreciated.

Here is my index method :

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Session["num"] = Posts;
        //Posts = new List<string> { "element1", "element2", "element3" };
        return View();
    }
```

And here is my view :

```
  <h2>Index</h2>

@foreach (@item c in @Session["num"])
{

}
```

Comment: @foreach (var c in (List<string>)@Session["num"])
    {
     @c
        <br>
    }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to cast your session variable since it's an object.

Something like...

```
@{ 
    var posts = Session["num"] as List<string>;
    if (posts != null) {
        foreach (var item in posts) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. Working perfect! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged this question as [asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc), why not take advantage of the framework?

**Model**

```
class MyModel
{
    public List<string> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

**View** (Index.cshtml)

```
@model MyModel

<h2>Index</h2>
@foreach(var post in Model.Posts)
{
    <span>@post</span>
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyModel();
    model.Posts = Posts; //Posts = new List<string> { "element1", "element2", "element3" };
    return View(model);
}
```